# Is dueling permitted?

Tags: sharia

Is dueling permitted in Islam? If so, what are the terms? For example, if one man has a wife who has been taken in war (not given over by her father) and another man demands her, can the suitor challenge the possessor to a duel for the woman?

Comment: A wife can not be taken by war, maybe you are talking about a slave concubine.   
Muslim cultures have a strong sense of Ghira' and eyeing the wife or concubine of another person would be very dishonorable and strongly disproved. Fighting between Muslims is not permissible. However friendly martial competitions are permissible, including ones which have a prize - I suppose some forms of dueling could fall into this.

Comment: @UmH Are you implying that Safiyah bint Huyayy, the mother of believers, was not the Prophet's wife?

Comment: She was his wife, she was originally a non-muslim who was captured during war and enslaved, then she accepted Islam and was freed and then married. I didn't realize you were talking about this route.